# How to parse a CSV file that does not have a separator in Python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

My CSV files after decryption are not having any separator and all the data is within quotes.

Sample CSV file data:

```
"text""1""0.2""true"
"text""1""0.2""true"
```

Comment: This isn't CSV input though. The C stands for 'character'. CSV isn't exactly a standard but your average CSV parser library is going to interpret those paired-up quotes as escaped quotes. i.e. that will be a single column, containing a string with 't', 'e', 'x', 't', '"' (one double quote), 1, another double quote, 0, dot, 2, double quote, t, r, u, e.

Comment: _if_ the input is never actually going to contain actual double quotes, _and_ every field is necessarily quote-delimited (either one is feasible in CSV input), the simplest thing is to just apply a global 'replace `""` with `";"`' to the entire file and then parse it with whatever CSV parser you want.

Comment: If one or both of those conditions do not hold (the actual text being conveyed in the file you have can contain quotes, which are presumably _also_ showing in the file in the form of 2 consecutive double quotes - and/or not all 'fields' are surrounded by quotes) then this data is __not possible__ to parse without involving AI or some such. Go back to the source that gives you these broken files and fix it _there_, or demand that they fix it if it's out of your control.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Actually, it kind of [is a standard.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html)

Comment: It's the internet. It's about de facto, not de jure. Someone tells you "I have this CSV" and the odds it exactly fits that spec is.. not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your columns are ALWAYS quoted, you can treat a quote or two consecutive quotes as one delimiter and then drop the fore and the hind empty columns:

```
pd.read_csv("foo.csv", delimiter='""?', header=None, engine='python')\
  .dropna(axis=1)
#      1  2    3     4
#0  text  1  0.2  True
#1  text  1  0.2  True
```

Answer (score 3):

Try stripping off the first and last character and then use "" as a separator

Say you read the string into csvstr

```
#              ,-- strips off the first and last character
#              |            ,-- the separator
items = csvstr[1:-1].split('""')
```

items will now contain the list

Answer (score 2):

If the input is completely consistent (there will never be a doubled double-quote within a value), then all you need to do is run the input through a stream editor (i.e. `sed` for instance) and replace all `""` with `","` turning it into a CSV file.

```
sed -e's/""/","/g' input.file > csv.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit out of scope but you could write your own parser:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = """

"text""1""0.2""true"
"text""1""0.2""true"

"""

class MyWannabeCSV(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        content     = line+
        line        = nl? field+ nl?
        field       = sep value sep
        value       = ~r'[^"]+'
        sep         = '"'

        nl          = ~'\n+'
        """
    )

    def visit_line(self, node, visited_children):
        _, fields, _ = visited_children
        return fields

    def visit_field(self, node, visited_children):
        _, value, _ = visited_children
        return value.text

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node



my_csv = MyWannabeCSV()
fields = my_csv.parse(data)
print(fields)
```

Which would yield

```
[['text', '1', '0.2', 'true'], ['text', '1', '0.2', 'true']]
```